# Functional Components: Accessing Shared States

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

How can I alter the state of the hook **isSignup** per click of a button and return it to **Auth.js** using functional components?

I can't figure out how to wrap the return statement inside the button. I keep getting _onClick is not a function error.

Note: Homepage.js and Auth.js are functional components and they are using shared states.

```
    // Homepage.js    
    const Homepage = () => {
        const [isSignup, setIsSignup] = useState(false);

        const handleClick = (e) => {
            if (e) {
                return <Auth isSignup={true}></Auth>
            }
            return <Auth isSignup={false}></Auth>
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <Button component={Link} to="auth" onClick={() => handleClick(false)}>
                    login
                </Button>
                <Button component={Link} to="auth" onClick={() => handleClick(true)}>
                    signup
                </Button>
            </div>
   }

// Auht.js
const Auth = (props) => {
    if(props.isSignup) {
    // display signup form....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

onClick is expecting a function, so,

```
onClick={handleClick}
```

The signature of handleClick is like this,

```
const handleClick = (event : React.ChangeEvent<any>) => {}
```

From the event, you can get the button id or something to determine the action.

Comment: True, if you want to pass  a parameter to the function `onClick={() => handleClick(false)}`

Comment: I am getting "Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files" error

Comment: Just remove it then. const handleClick = (event ) => {}